# Outlook Interop AdvancedSearch call fails with filter

Tags: outlook, interop, advanced-search

I'm trying to run the AdvancedSearch function on the Outlook.Application class but I'm receiving an exception with the message "The operation has failed.". How do I get this to complete successfully?

I was previously using the basic search function with success to search a folder. I now have a need for my code to identify if the search produced any results. Therefore I require the advanced search function. When I call the function without a filter specified, outlook will successfully navigate to the folder. When I include the filter value an exception is raised. I'm not checking for it here but the IsInstantSearchEnabled property is true.

```
Dim scope = $"'{searchFolder.FolderPath}'"
Dim searchAttachment = "https://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0EA5001E"
Dim filter = $"@SQL={Chr(34)}{searchAttachment}{Chr(34)} ci_phrasematch '{searchText}'"
Dim search = app.AdvancedSearch(scope, filter)
```

scope: '\???\Inbox\???'

filter: @SQL="https://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0EA5001E" ci_phrasematch '???'

??? are just replaced values for this posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the filter argument on AdvancedSearch needs the '@SQL=' portion omitted in order to function whereas other methods require it. Removing that portion of the string fixed it.